# Refresh partial page on user control text change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have one Usercontrol Textbox with some radio buttons.
I want to refresh some of these buttons when I change the usercontrol textbox value.

In short, when I select Specific button it displays RM row & for All radio button selection it hides RM row. After selecting RM & checking Client radio button, it again displays two radio button below. By checking any of radio it displays the grid data below. For Prospect & Closed button it displays grid data below after checking it.

For all radio all the functionality is same except RM selection.

My all functionality is working as expected just need to add one more addition in it.

Now I want to refresh 5 radio buttons(Client, Prospect, Closed, Client, Family) which are below RM user control screen when I change the RM name from usercontrol textbox.

I tried using update panel but it couldn't work as it got mess for me so reverted all that changes. My current working code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $110 = $;

    $110(document).ready(function () {
        //intial setting of panel
        rdoBtnShowHidePanels();
        $110("#trClient").hide();
        $110("#btnSendSms").hide();
        $110("#trCommMode").hide();
        $110("input[type='radio'][name='First']").attr('checked', false);

        $110("input[type='radio'][name='SelectRM']").change(function () {
            $110("#trClient").hide();
            $110("#jqxContact").hide();
            $110("#trCommMode").hide();

            if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='RdoSpecific']").is(":checked") == true) {
                $110("input[type='radio'][name='First']").attr('checked', false);
                $110("input[type='radio'][name='a']").attr('checked', false);
                $110("#trRM").show();
                $("input[id$=mcscRMSearch_txtSearch]").val('');

                $110("input[type='radio'][name='First']").change(function () {
                    if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='RdoSpecific']").is(":checked") == true) {
                        if (ValidateRMSelection() == true) {

                            $110("#trRM").show();
                            if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='rdoClientAll']").is(":checked") == true) {
                                $110("#trClient").show();
                                $110("input[type='radio'][name='a']").change(function () {
                                    $110("#hdnType").val("C");
                                    $110("#jqxContact").show();

                                    var getselectedrowindexes = $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
                                    $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('unselectrow', getselectedrowindexes);
                                    $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('clearselection');
                                    if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='RdoSpecific']").is(":checked") == true) {
                                        BindGridBasedOnRadioButtons();
                                    }
                                    $110("#trCommMode").show();
                                    return;
                                })
                            }
                            else {
                                $110("#hdnType").val("P");
                                $110("input[type='radio'][id='rdoclient']").prop("checked", false);
                                $110("input[type='radio'][id='rdofamily']").prop("checked", false);
                                $110("#trClient").hide();
                                $110("#jqxContact").show();
                                var getselectedrowindexes = $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
                                $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('unselectrow', getselectedrowindexes);
                                $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('clearselection');
                                if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='RdoSpecific']").is(":checked") == true) {
                                    BindGridBasedOnRadioButtons();
                                }
                                $110("#trCommMode").show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Select RM");
                            $110("#trClient").hide();
                            $110("#trCommMode").hide();
                            $110("#jqxContact").hide();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                $110("#trRM").hide();
                $110("#trCommMode").hide();
                $110("input[type='radio'][name='First']").attr('checked', false);
                $110("input[type='radio'][name='a']").attr('checked', false);
                $110("input[type='radio'][name='First']").change(function () {
                    if ($110("input[type='radio'][id='rdoClientAll']").is(":checked") == true) {
                        $110("#jqxContact").hide()
                        $110("#trClient").show();
                        $110("input[type='radio'][name='a']").change(function () {
                            $110("#hdnType").val("C");
                            $110("#jqxContact").show();
                            var getselectedrowindexes = $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
                            $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('unselectrow', getselectedrowindexes);
                            $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('clearselection');

                            BindGridBasedOnRadioButtons1();
                            $110("#trCommMode").show();
                            return;
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        $110("#hdnType").val("P");
                        $110("input[type='radio'][id='rdoclient']").prop("checked", false);
                        $110("input[type='radio'][id='rdofamily']").prop("checked", false);
                        $110("#trClient").hide();
                        $110("#jqxContact").show();
                        var getselectedrowindexes = $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');
                        $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('unselectrow', getselectedrowindexes);
                        $110('#jqxContact').jqxGrid('clearselection');

                        BindGridBasedOnRadioButtons1();
                        $110("#trCommMode").show();
                        return;
                    }
                })
            }
        })

<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scmPhoneBook" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="clsTitle" align="center" style="height: 25px">Contacts
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="clstd" align="left" style="width: 100%" colspan="2">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clstdnext" align="left" style="width: 100%" colspan="2">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RdoSpecific" runat="server" GroupName="SelectRM" Text="Specific"></asp:RadioButton>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RdoAll" runat="server" GroupName="SelectRM" Text="All"></asp:RadioButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="trRM">
                        <td class="clstd" width="2%">RM
                        </td>
                        <td class="clstd" width="98%">
                            <mwimcs:MultiColumnSearchControl
                                runat="server"
                                ID="mcscRMSearch"
                                CssClass="clsTextbox"
                                Width="300"
                                ControlType="137"
                                DataTextField="usr_name"
                                DataValueField="usr_id"
                                Top="-15px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="clstdnext" align="left" style="width: 100%" colspan="2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoClientAll" runat="server" GroupName="First" Text="Client"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RdoProspect" runat="server" GroupName="First" Text="Prospect"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RdoClosed" runat="server" GroupName="First" Text="Closed"></asp:RadioButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trClient">
            <td class="clstd" align="left" style="width: 100%" colspan="2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdofamily" runat="server" GroupName="a" Text="Family"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoclient" runat="server" GroupName="a" Text="Client"></asp:RadioButton>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div id="jqxContact"></div>
                <asp:Panel ID="PnlClient" runat="server" Width="100%">
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
            <asp:DataGrid ID="dgCompany" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25">
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />


    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" border="0">
        <tr height="10px">
            <td class="clsLabel_err" colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" CssClass="clsLabel_err"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width: 100%" id="trCommMode">
            <td class="clstdnext" style="width: 25%">Communication Mode:</td>
            <td class="clstdnext" align="left" valign="middle">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnlistSmsMail" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px">
                    <asp:ListItem>
                    SMS
                    </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>
                    E-Mail
                    </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="pnlEmailDtls" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlpnlEmailDtls" runat="server" Width="100%">
                    <table id="Table3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstd" style="width: 25%">Email From</td>
                            <td class="clsTd" style="width: 80%">
                                <cc1:MultiColumnComboBox ID="mmcEmail" runat="server" CssClass="clstd" HeaderCSS="clsReportTitle"
                                    ItemsCSS="clstdnext" VerticalScrolling="True" DownArrowButtonCSS="clsButton"
                                    DownArrowImageURL="url(Images/downarrow.gif)" DownArrowButtonHeight="12" DownArrowButtonWidth="20"
                                    TextBoxCSS="clsTextbox">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <cc1:Column ColumnWidth="" DataField="email" KeyColumn="True" HeaderText="Email"></cc1:Column>
                                        <cc1:Column ColumnWidth="" DataField="smtp" KeyColumn="False" HeaderText="SMTP"></cc1:Column>
                                    </Columns>
                                </cc1:MultiColumnComboBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstdnext" style="width: 20px">Subject</td>
                            <td class="clstdnext" style="width: 80px">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="clsTextbox" Width="327px">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstd">Attachment 1)
                            </td>
                            <td class="clstd">
                                <input class="clsTextbox" id="fileupload1" style="width: 250px" type="file" size="48" runat="server"
                                    name="fileupload1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstdnext">Attachment 2)
                            </td>
                            <td class="clstdnext">
                                <input class="clsTextbox" id="fileupload2" style="width: 250px" type="file" size="48" runat="server"
                                    name="fileupload2" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstd">Attachment 3)
                            </td>
                            <td class="clstd">
                                <input class="clsTextbox" id="fileupload3" style="width: 250px" type="file" size="48" runat="server"
                                    name="fileupload3" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clsReportTitle" align="center" style="width: 100%" colspan="2">Message
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%--<TD width="100%" colSpan=2> 
                            <asp:TextBox id=txtMessage runat="server" CssClass="clsTextbox" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="250px"></asp:TextBox></TD>--%>
                            <td align="left" class="clstd" colspan="2">
                                <ftb:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox1" EnableHtmlMode="false" ToolbarLayout="ParagraphMenu, FontFacesMenu, FontSizesMenu, FontForeColorsMenu,FontForeColorPicker, FontBackColorsMenu, FontBackColorPicker, Bold, Italic, Underline,Strikethrough, Superscript, Subscript|InsertImageFromGallery, CreateLink, Unlink, JustifyLeft, JustifyRight, JustifyCenter, JustifyFull,BulletedList, NumberedList, Indent, Outdent,Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, Undo, Redo,Save,InsertRule, InsertDate,InsertTime,Preview"
                                    Height="300px" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                </ftb:FreeTextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 100%" class="clstd_btn" colspan="2">
                                <%--<input id="BtnSendEmail" type="button" class="clsButton" value="Send"/>--%>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnSendEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidationBeforeEmailSendClick();" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Send"></asp:Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="pnlSmsDtls" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlpnlSmsDtls" runat="server" Width="100%">
                    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clstd" style="width: 25%">SMS Type
                            </td>
                            <td class="clstd">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSmsType" CssClass="clsCombobox" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">---Select---</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Upcoming maturity/due date</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">New product offerings</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Pick of the day</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="clstdnext">SMS Text
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="clstdnext" style="height: 40px">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSmsText" runat="server" CssClass="clsTextbox" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                    Width="100%" Height="100px">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="clstd_btn">
                                <input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Save" class="clsButton" />
                                <%--<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Save" />--%>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSendSms" runat="server" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Send SMS"
                                    Width="72px"></asp:Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnType" />
</form>
```

Its argent... kindly please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put this is jsFiddle?